# Funcion Javascript para copiar texto

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

Quería hacer una función para poder asignarle a un boton donde al clickearlo se te guarde en la papelera un texto. Como puedo hacerlo? actualmente tengo éste código pero no funciona y no se porqué ya que lo leí en internet y no lo desarrollé yo. Gracias!

```
  function copyToClipboard(text) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
  }
```

Comment: que se guarde un texto en la papelera ? que significa esto ?

Comment: no se si es la mejor manera de explicarlo pero seria que se te quede copiado, como el boton que tienen muchas paginas para copiarte un texto y pegarlo donde quieras. Decime si se entendió. Gracias

Comment: Portapapeles querrás decir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo resolvi

```
  function copyText() {
    // Get the text inside the <p> tag
    var text = document.querySelector('#text').innerText;
    
    // Create a temporary textarea element to copy the text
    var tempTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    tempTextArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);
    
    // Select the text inside the textarea element
    tempTextArea.select();
    
    // Copy the text to the clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    // Remove the temporary textarea element
    document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);
```

}

Comment: Si tomaste el código de otro lugar, deja un enlace por lo menos.

Comment: Y una explicación de lo que hace el código...